# How to pass parameters in index function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

here's an example of url: 
http://www.example.com/search/search-keyword

I am trying to make this work, I removed the index.php using .htaccess, search is the controller and I want to pass a parameter in the index method.

this is currently what it looks like:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{

    function index($param){
        echo $param;
    }

}
```

any suggestions? I can't seem to make it work

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 35):

- You need the `index` segment `http://www.example.com/search/index/search-keyword`.
- Or you need to use a route `$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';`
- Or you can look at [remap](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)

Remember not to trust user input, especially when you are throwing it into your url. The latest version of CI supports `$_GET` variables now, so you may want to look into using that or [flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html). A searh term as simple as `O' Brien` will give you a fatal error ("The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.").

Comment: Isn't it possible to URLencode the query parameter and then decode it in the controller?

Comment: @pat: No, you will still get errors. However, you could encrypt the parameter - but that would just be pointless. You could also use session or post data, but then it wouldn't show up in the url.

Comment: ya 1st option really worked for me  simply specifying function name after controller name (as we regularly do to call other functions. eg `href="<?php echo base_url()."usage/index/$selected_next_date"; ?>" `

Comment: This should be marked as correct solution. Though in CodeIgniter 4 the syntax for adding the route in `Routes.php` is `$routes->add('search/(:any)', 'search/index/$1');` . This correctly reply to the original question and the code of the original question will work with no modifications. In fact the URI will work as expected with `http://www.example.com/search/{$param}`

Comment: Sorry I have a corrige: 
this wont' work as expected `$routes->add('search/(:any)', 'search/index/$1');` 
instead you must use `$routes->add('search/(:any)', 'search/$1');` otherwise it will be passed "index" as parameter . Apparently a no sense, but I suppose it is because of the mechanism that removes the "index.php" from the CodeIgniter URI

Answer (score 27):

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{

    function _remap($param) {
        $this->index($param);
    }

    function index($param){
        echo $param;
    }

}
```

You should then be able to access that as: /search/123123  :and the page would echo out "123123" or whatever you put in place of that.

Comment: that works fine, but I wonder if it's the right way to do

Answer (score 13):

```
function _remap($parameter){

        $this->_index($parameter);

}
```

Give it a try and tell us how it went.

Answer (score 6):

Most of these solutions will only work if you only have a single function called `index()` in your controller. If you have this in your routes:

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';
```

With the above in your routes, what will happen is that your search function will work but then if you add any other functions to that same controller they'll all be redirected to `/search/index/$1`.

The only solution I can think of that allows you to use the URL you want while still being able to add any other functions to your search controller is to add a sort of messy conditional to your routes file. Here's what it will look like and what it does:

`$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Only add this for readability
if(!strpos($request, 'search/another_function') || !strpos($request, 'search/more_functions')) {
    $route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';
}`

What this is doing is basically saying "if the requested URL doesn't contain the name of any of my search controller functions then it must be meant for the index so we'll activate the route rule for index".

This will allow you to take requests for `search/any_other_functions_you_have` without issue and only activate the rule for hiding the index function when a request URI doesn't match any of them.

One side effect of this is that you'll never get a 404. For example, if someone enters a URL like "yourdomain.com/search/something" and they expect it to show a non-search result page they won't get a 404 alerting them to the fact that there is no page like that and instead the app will assume what they typed is a search term. However, it sounds like this isn't much of an issue for you and I don't see it being such a terrible thing for one controller to be unabe to return 404s.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand the way code igniter urls work, its basically like this:

http://www.mysite.com/{controller}/{function}

So what your url is actually looking a function called "keyword" in your search controller.

You have multiple options. The easiest will be to simply change the url to:

http://www.mysite.com/search/result/keyword

Then this should work perfectly:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{

function result($param){
 echo $param;
}

}
```

If you really want to use the url as you had it, you can use the same snippet of code as above but also open up "application/config/routes.php" and add this to the bottom.

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = "search/result";
```

Alternatively if you want to continue using the index function you can change it to this

```
    $route['search/(:any)'] = "search/index";
```

And change your class to something like this:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{

  function index($param=FALSE){
    if($param == FALSE) {
      //Show search box
    } else {
      //Show search results
    }
  }

}
```

Don't forget to update your answer if you figure it out yourself or accept somebodies answer if it answers it :)

Comment: That's really cool, it works. But how to access the parameter that is passing to index function?

Answer (score 1):

I've just started CI and here was my solution and implemented it on my website. So far it works for me and my search queries have been indexed by google as links

```
Class Search extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){

    $search_item = $this->input->post('search_box'); // this is from the input field

    redirect(base_url()."search/q/".url_title($search_item));

    }



 //  i've redirected it to the "search" controller then :

     function q($search_item = null){// process search
    // load the view here with the data
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

From CI userGuide

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'some_method')
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
       $this->default_method();
    }
}
```

So I've created my controller in this way:

```
class Shortener extends CI_Controller {
function shortener() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function index($getVar) {
    echo "Get var: " . $getVar;
}

function config() {
    echo "another function";
}

function _remap($method) {
    if($method == "config") {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else {

        $this->index($method);
    }
}
}
```

Hope this can be helpful to someone...

BUG: if you call /shortener _remap function pass "index" to index() function...it can be solved adding an if condition or something else

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CI URI Class. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{

     function index($param){
        //echo the search-keyword
        echo $this->uri->segment(2);
     }

}
```

Comment: This won't work because the index function is not invoked, its looking for the non-existent function 'search-keyword'

Comment: How about declaring the uri segment 2 as your search keyword in a construct?

Answer (score 0):

This easiest way is just to use [uri segments](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html):

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{
  function index(){
    $param=$this->uri->segment(2);
    echo $param;
  }
}
```

Or like Madmartigan said, use routes, which is probably the better way of doing this.

Comment: This won't work because the index function is not invoked, its looking for the non-existent function 'search-keyword'

Comment: Very true, you need to add a route anyway, so I guess it's best just to use the route method

Comment: You can use php5 `__call` as well, similar to how you'd use CI's `_remap`. I personally like to keep my routes clean and lean, so I am fond of those methods for simple controllers that only do one or two things.

Answer (score 0):

I had to also check if some variable was passed or not - so here is the solution that I took.

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Story extends CI_Controller{

    function story() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function _remap($parameter){
        $this->_index($parameter);
    }  

    public function _index($story_id) {        
        if($story_id == 'index'){
            //No variable passed
            redirect('auth', 'refresh');
        }else{
            $data['title'] = "Story";
            $this->load->view('story', $data);                
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. This code works for me. If parameter is a number

```
Or you need to use a route $route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';
```

However, If the parameter is a string (http://[::1]/note/getnote/index/fg => http://[::1]/note/getnote/fg). I use _remap() like this code.

```
<?php
```

class Getnote extends CI_Controller
{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
}

public function index(){

}

public function _remap($keyname)
{
    $this->load->model('Laydb');
    $data = $this->Laydb->getNote($keyname);
    $proListArray['patitle'] = "Edit notepad";

    $this->load->view('top', $proListArray);
    $this->load->view('editblog', $data);
    $this->load->view('bottom');
}
```

}

Comment: How is different from @Bill answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{

    function index($param){
        echo $param;
    }

}
```

In routes.php

```
$routes['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';
```

It's all

Answer (score -2):

I finally found a workaround since I cant simply put post variables into the URL.

What I did was create another function, then redirect it to that function.

```
 class Search extends CI_Controller{
   function index(){
        $search_item = $this->input-post('search_item');
        redirect("search/q/".url_title($search_item));
  }

  function q($key){
    // process search
  }
 }
```

Comment: This alters the search term, which is not desirable. If I searched for `Hello World!` you would return results for `hello-world`