# CodeIgniter - cannot set routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, controller

I have a problem with CI. I have a model:

```
public function Game($id) {
    $id = (int)$id;

    $q = $this -> db -> get_where('games', array('id' => $id));
    return $q -> row_array();
}
```

Controller for it:

```
public function index($gameID) {
    $data['game'] = $this->games_model->Game($gameID);
    $this -> load -> view('games/game', $data);
}
```

And a problem ;) I've set my routing as follows:

```
$route['games/(:num)'] = 'games/game/$1';
$route['games'] = 'games/game/game';
```

But it doesn't work at all. My controller dir is `games/game.php` (with function `Game` inside). My problem is - how can I pass `$id` for it? I am very new to CI, but I couldn't find solution for this in docs.

Comment: What errors are you getting? The routing seems fine, but I'm a little confused with your controller structure.

Comment: I'm getting 404. Why are you confused?

Comment: Too many games... :) Seriously now, you get 404 only when going to routed url (e.g. 'games/21') or to the full url as well ('games/game/21' or 'games/game/index.php/21')?

Comment: And what does this do: `$route['games/(:num)'] = 'games/game/index/$1';`?

Comment: I like to have my thing separates, so I try to keep everything in differnent files. `games/game/index/$1` is `games(dir)/game(file)/index(class)/$1(parameter)`. But, I've made it. It was my mistake. Good route is (modified to use with my slug) `$route['games/(:any)-(:num)'] = 'games/game/game/$2';`

Comment: Ah, so you're using something like `gameName-21`. Should've shown a sample url, but the most important thing is that you've solved it.

Comment: I thought that showing `route` is sufficient ;) Anyway, thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$route['games'] = 'games/game/index'; // Folder/Controller/Function
$route['games/(:num)'] = 'games/game/index/$1'; // Folder/Controller/Function/Method
$route['games/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'games/game/index/$1/$2';
```

If you want to use slug, [url_title($title, 'underscore', TRUE)](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) it help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [remap](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) or you will have to modify your routes path again. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545507/how-to-pass-paramaters-in-index-function-in-codeigniter) question, that's been asked here.