# code igniter active records where URI segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having problems when getting the segment. I'm always getting a 404 error.

Here is the model:

```
class Site_model extends CI_Model {

    function getRecords()
    {
        $this->db->where('lvlOne', end($this->uri->segment_array()) );
        $query = $this->db->get('mph_products', 8);

        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

    function index ()
    {
        $data['records'] = $this->site_model->getRecords();

        $this->load->view('main', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What url are you navigating to and what are your routes?

Comment: First find out that you can access the function. Type a single `echo 'ok';` And see if it prints ok.

Comment: you should probably grab the segment in the controller and do some verification on i rather than just assuming its valid in your model.  Although I guess you could be doing that in the constructor...

Comment: I've got access to the function. the route is: http://localhost/franca/menkenPh/index.php/site/argument

Comment: you get 404 because codeigniter expects you to have a method in your controller with the argument value, remember CI's url structure `index.php/controller/method` if that's how you want your URLs to look then [create a route](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) that redirects every request to site to the index method

Comment: Check [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545507/how-to-pass-paramaters-in-index-function-in-codeigniter) for more info

Comment: How do I do that? Something like this?
    $route['index.php/site/'] = "site/index";