# CodeIgniter User Input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just begun with CI and I now got stuck that I don't know how to process user input.

The application is reading api-data from certain resources (I implemented that as model) and now I want to allow the user to send data to an API. I need no login or similar on that application, it just has 2 textfields and what's entered there is send thru the API as command. The intex page would then reload and request all APIs again getting the updated data and also the result of the input.

Where do I process the input now? All tutorials I found tell me about user login with an user controler class or blogposts with a blog class and so on. I dont want that I just want to grab user input and send it thru an api. Would I just throw it into the index() method of my API controller or how?

TIA

Comment: please post some code next time, but as I can understand your question, yes you can grab user input in index() via `$this->input->post('fild')`, or `$this->input->get('field')`, but remember `index()` does not accept parameters.

Comment: @Kyslik `but remember index() does not accept parameters.` Not true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545507/how-to-pass-paramaters-in-index-function-in-codeigniter

Comment: @Kyslik is right.  You can get post data with $this->input->post('fieldname') or get all post data with something like this: $dat a= $this->input->post() except for the index() portion.  index() can accept params you just have to specify them.  for example: index ($field1=NULL,$field2)

Comment: @HashemQolami explain more so OP understands dont just cite. (I am not native english speaker so my explanation might be badly interpreted...), remaping does not count because you do not use `index()` do you? You are just trying to trash my comment. `index()` in CI does not accept params because router looks for method with name of indexes pseudo "parameter" unless you remap or reroute. `server/controller/method`

Comment: I can figure out with the index() however my problem was, that I just didnt know how to handle that in a CI-manner. Tutorials show things like creating an user controller and then handle the loginform there, but I want everything on one page and there is no need for logins or sessions.
I didnt post code because there is not much to see: Theres a apidisplay that extends CI_controller and function index() getting data from api_odel->getApiData() and pushing that to $this->load->view('apiview', $data). I want to get user input like $this->input->get('complexview') to display more detailed tables

Comment: Or what if user sends a comand to the api like if(!empty($this->input->post('changeAddr'))) this->api_model->sendData('changeAddr', $this->input->post('changeAddr'))
Do I handle *everything* in index()??